# Can I add a classname to a CSS variable?

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

Is it possible to add a classname to a CSS variable or is there some other way to set it up so that I don't have to manipulate each individual variable directly via javascript? I'd like to keep all my styles in CSS and simply turn on relevant classes with JS. For example, If something like this was possible in CSS:

```
:root.white{ --bgcol:#FFF; --col:#000; }
:root.black{ --bgcol:#000; --col:#FFF; }
```

Then I could then just toggle the `.black` or `.white` class from javascript to trigger all vars to change. What's the best approach for this type of setup?

Comment: apply this to the `body` instead of the root element and your done. CSS variable doesn't need to be defined in root

Comment: appy to `body` or some *wrappping div* instead of `:root`...

Comment: The convention has always been to define global custom properties in :root, even if [nobody knows or has ever questioned why](https://twitter.com/NOVALISTIC/status/998844347343822849). Deviating from convention presents no benefits whatsoever.

Comment: @BoltClock true, but in this case where we need to consider class switching better target body or html where it's easy to manipulate with JS.

Comment: @Temani Afif: :root is html. I don't see how `document.querySelector('body').className = ...` or `document.body.className = ...` would be any easier than `document.querySelector(':root').className = ...` or `document.documentElement.className = ...` in JS.

Comment: @BoltClock probably because it's not intuitive. The OP is not aware it's possible thus the question (I my self never played with `:root` using JS by the way)

Comment: @Temani Afif: Not understanding :root is not a reason to avoid using it or to break convention in ways that could potentially break stylesheets (specificity, inheritance, etc). It is a reason to learn about it so you can make the most out of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's frankly the best (as in most idiomatic) approach — the use of class names, if not altogether separate stylesheets ([as has been tradition for many, many years](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.en.html)), to theme entire layouts via custom properties. It's the most "fundamentally CSS" approach with JavaScript merely being the glue that makes the theme switching work. You really can't do much better than that.

For those unaware what `:root` means and wondering where exactly the class names are being applied, it's the `html` element (the parent of `body`). So there is nothing special going on here — you're simply switching class names on the `html` element. It just happens that global custom properties are conventionally defined for the document root element since it's at the top level of the inheritance chain.

If you have any theme-agnostic custom properties, as well as style properties (i.e. not custom properties) that apply to the root element, keep them in their own unqualified `:root` rule, separate from your themed custom properties, so they won't be affected by theme switching. Here's an example:

```js
const root = document.documentElement;

// Default theme - should assign declaratively in markup, not JS
// For a classless default theme, move its custom properties to unqualified :root
// Again, keep it separate from the other :root rule that contains non-theme props
// Remember, the cascade is your friend, not the enemy
root.classList.add('white');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  root.classList.toggle('white');
  root.classList.toggle('black');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --spacing: 1rem;
  color: var(--col);
  background-color: var(--bgcol);
}

:root.white {
  --bgcol: #FFF;
  --col: #000;
}

:root.black {
  --bgcol: #000;
  --col: #FFF;
}

p {
  margin: var(--spacing);
  border: thin dashed;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}
```

```html
<button>Switch themes</button>
<p>Hello world!
```

Comment: Very cool and exactly what I wanted. It's funny I was so close with my hypothetical. I had no idea `:root` was just the `html` tag. Thanks!

Comment: I considered that after the conversation under your question, so I figured it wouldn't hurt to add a primer. I'm glad I did now, and glad you learned something new.

Comment: @BoltClock Shouldn't you use `classList.toggle` in order to avoid breaking other class use on the element?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Sure. I wasn't thinking too much about JS robustness when putting this together, but I've updated it.

Answer (score 5):

Using `:root` selector is identical to using `html`, except its specifity is higher, thus there is no issues in using this approach.

For example:

```css
:root {
  --bg: red;
}
:root.blue {
  --bg: blue;
}
// ...
div {
  background: var(--bg);
}
```

Later, you should just change `html`'s class and variables will change.

You can see an example [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6r9cmy0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:scope` for it. The example from MDN demonstrates exactly this use case:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope